# Difference between "stammer" and "stutter"?

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference in meaning between "stammer" and "stutter"? Are they completely synonymous?

Comment: The two verbs are synonyms.  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stammer_1?q=stammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It depends who you ask](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/stammering-and-stuttering.html). And it may depend on how technical you want to get. As speech impediments, some people define them as being different. But others say the main difference is that British English prefers *stammer* and American English *stutter*. If you do not wish to examine the possible techinical differences between the words, you should at least be aware of the regional difference in usage.

Comment: Rather than simply linking to an article, it would be preferable if you would include the relevant part of it here, in the case that the site changes their URL structure or closes down entirely.